# How did Selene get pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, underworld, underworld-awakening

In [Underworld Awakening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld%3a_Awakening) Selene is captured and cryonically frozen after a bomb grenade hit her and Michael underwater.

She awakes 12 years later to find out she has a daughter, and apparently Michael is the biological father.

But I can't recollect that they actually ever explained where the daughter came from? Was Selene pregnant when they caught her? Or was the baby produced in the lab with DNA from both captives?

Maybe I just missed that part, I hope someone can clear that up.

Comment: Well, they did have happy fun time in the second movie, so....

Comment: Ok maybe the title should rather read: "Was Selene pregnant?" I am familiar with the general way how this works. ;)

Comment: Well, you see, when two people love each other they...

Comment: Well, Selene did do it with Michael after she almost burned to death in the truck in the big warehouse in Underworld: Evolution. So that would explain a lot.

Comment: I personally think that Selene was already pregnant when they were captured but that's just me

Comment: "When a mommy vampire and a daddy hybrid love each other very much..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Eve is the three-way hybrid daughter of Selene and Michael Corvin,
>   through whom she is a descendant of Alexander Corvinus. In Underworld:
>   Awakening, she tells Selene that her names is Subject 2. **She was born
>   without her parents' knowledge during their 12-year captivity in
>   Antigen.** [Note] (this is also confirmed in bonus material on the DVD & Blu-ray).  The scientists in the facility told her that her parents were
>   dead. **After her escape, Selene discovers that she had given birth to
>   Eve during her unconscious state.** Being pursued by both humans and
>   Lycans because of her unique origin, and despite Selene's attempts to
>   shield her from the dangers around them. Although never referred to as
>   "Eve" in the film, the name has caught on among fans of the series.
>   She is portrayed by India Eisley.

Note: "The first ten minutes of Underworld: Awakening is a prologue that explains everything that’s happened before the events of the film, then it cuts to 13 years later." ~ [Underworld: Awakening Set Visit interview; Producer Richard Wright Full Interview](http://collider.com/underworld-4-awakening-set-visit/)

These are the details from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_%28film_series%29).

Comment: I don’t understand why this was accepted, it doesn’t answer the question. The closest it comes is by assuming that if Selene was already pregnant, she knew about it which of course isn’t guaranteed (especially for someone busy fighting all the time).

Comment: @Synetech have you missed the highlighted words.

Comment: No, I did not; in fact I am talking *specifically* about them. The lines indicates that Selene didn’t know that Eve was born, but it says nothing about Selene knowing whether she was pregnant or not. She could have been pregnant already or the scientists could have extracted DNA and made her in a Petri dish.

Comment: It was never explained in movie or in any interview

Comment: `It was never explained in movie or in any interview`   Then *that is* the answer. `;-)`

Comment: @Synetech - Correction: That *would have been* the answer

Answer (score 4):

According to Selene's narration in *Underworld: Blood Wars*, Selene was unknowingly pregnant with Eve when Selene was captured. She must have only recently become pregnant, because she did not yet know about her daughter.

The time gap between *Underworld: Evolution* and *Underworld: Awakening* is too long for Selene to have become pregnant during *Evolution*. According to an [interview](http://www.gotham-news.com/node/12005) with Director Björn Stein, *Awakening* “picks up about six months after the end of the second” film.

Selene and Michael spent the time in between films together, and Selene became pregnant in the usual way.

Comment: I don't have a quote from _Blood Wars_ handy. I think it was part of the narration right at the start of the film, when Selene was explaining the backstory.

Comment: Ah yes, the usual way "*when a mummy vampire Princess and a daddy hybrid/vampire/werewolf/mutant love each other very much they dress up in skin-tight leather fetishwear..., etc"*